# How to create a .each loop to grab a key and value from a hash based on user input?

Tags: ruby

I created a hash of different types of lasers to use based on the distance of an object. I am looking to ask the user how far from the desired object they are and then give them the laser that they should use based on the user input.

I'm trying to implement a .each method so that I can iterate through the hash and find out where in the hash the user input should lie but I am struggling on implementing that concept into code. Bonus if you could teach me to implement my answer using .gsub("_", " ")

```
laserType = {
  blaster: 200,
  helium_neon: 180,
  nuclear_pumped: 170,
  krypton: 170,
  co2: 160,
  coil: 150,
  strontium_vapor: 140,
  ruby: 130,
  xenon_ion: 120,
  free_electron: 110,
  gas_dynamic: 95,
  nitrogen: 0
}

sortedLasers = laserType.sort_by { |name, range| range }


puts "How far away from the object are you?"
answer = gets.chomp

sortedLasers.each {|name, range| puts "#{key} is #{value}"};
```

EX:

"How far from the object are you?"

"165"

"You should use the co2 laser!"

Comment: Hashes are fast and efficient in looking up keys and delivering their values. The other way around: not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
answer = 120
laser = laserType.find { |type, distance| distance == answer }
# => [:xenon_ion, 120]

puts "Try using a #{laser.first.to_s.tr("_", " ")} laser."
```

If you want to match multiple lasers, instead of `find` you would use `select`, which will return an array of all of the matching values:

```
matches = laserType.select { |_, distance| distance == answer }
puts "Try using one of these: " + matches.map { |type, _| type.to_s.tr("_", " ") }.join(", ")
```

You can improve this by using a range (`10..15`) to allow for a range of distances:

```
laser_types = {
  blaster: 190..210,
  helium_neon: 170..190,
  free_electron: 70..150,
  nitrogen: 0..50,
}

laser_types.select { |_, range| range.cover?(answer) }
```

Comment: I suggest you only give the "You can improve this..." solution because obviously the given distance is not necessarily equal to one of the breakpoints. It could be `158` or possibly `158.72`, for example. In your hash `laser_types` I suggest you 1) use three dots for the ranges; 2) make one of the pairs `blaster: 200..Float::INFINITY`; and 3) add laser/range pairs to cover `0..Float::INFINITY`. There are now gaps between `170` and `190` and between `50` and `70`. You also need to tack `.first` onto the end of `laser_types.select {...}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I only provided the example values in the ranges as an example. I have no knowledge of the domain space and couldn't possibly suggest that any particular “laser type” is suitable for infinite-distance, and I don't see any reason to complicate matters with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a laser whose maximum range is closest to the user input but not less than that, then

```
laser_name = laser_types.each.lazy
  .select{|name, range| range >= answer}
  .min_by{|name, range| range}[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

I presume the mapping of distances to lasers is data, as opposed to a hash computed in the programme. If so, it makes sense to make it a constant:

```
MIN_DISTANCE_BY_LASER = {
  blaster:         200,
  helium_neon:     180,
  nuclear_pumped:  175,
  krypton:         170,
  co2:             160,
  coil:            150,
  strontium_vapor: 140,
  ruby:            130,
  xenon_ion:       120,
  free_electron:   110,
  gas_dynamic:      95,
  nitrogen:          0
}
```

We can write a method to return the desired laser as follows:

```
def laser_by_distance(distance)
  MIN_DISTANCE_BY_LASER.find { |_,d| distance > d }.first
end
```

```
laser_by_distance(43)  #=> :nitrogen 
laser_by_distance(95)  #=> :nitrogen 
laser_by_distance(126) #=> :xenon_ion 
laser_by_distance(154) #=> :coil 
laser_by_distance(170) #=> :co2 
laser_by_distance(200) #=> :helium_neon 
laser_by_distance(230) #=> :blaster
```

Interestingly, this same approach can be used for generating random variates from a discrete probability distribution function.

If speed is of the essence (not so much in this problem but for problems where the number of elements [pairs] in the array is relative large), one can exploit the fact that all distances in `MIN_DISTANCE_BY_LASER` are multiples of `5`. The idea is avoid a linear search through the hash to find the desired laser for a given distance, but instead to obtain the laser by computing, from the distance, an offset into an array of lasers.

```
arr = MIN_DISTANCE_BY_LASER.to_a.reverse
  #=> [[:nitrogen, 0],[:gas_dynamic, 95], [:free_electron, 110],
  #    [:xenon_ion, 120], [:ruby, 130], [:strontium_vapor, 140],
  #    [:coil, 150], [:co2, 160], [:krypton, 170],
  #    [:nuclear_pumped, 175], [:helium_neon, 180], [:blaster, 200]]
LASER_BY_INTERVAL = (1..arr.size-2).    
  flat_map { |i| [arr[i][0]] * ((arr[i+1][1] - arr[i][1])/5) }
  #=> [:gas_dynamic, :gas_dynamic, :gas_dynamic,
  #    :free_electron, :free_electron,
  #    :xenon_ion, :xenon_ion,
  #    :ruby, :ruby,
  #    :strontium_vapor, :strontium_vapor,
  #    :coil, :coil,
  #    :co2, :co2,
  #    :krypton,
  #    :nuclear_pumped,
  #    :helium_neon, :helium_neon, :helium_neon, :helium_neon]       
MIN_DST = arr[1][1] #=> 95
MIN_LSR = arr[0][0] #=> :nitrogen
MAX_LSR, MAX_DST = arr[-1]
  #=> [:blaster, 200]
```

We may now write the method.

```
def laser_by_distance(dst)
  case
  when dst <= MIN_DST
    MIN_LSR
  when dst > MAX_DST
    MAX_LSR
  else
    LASER_BY_INTERVAL[(dst-MIN_DST).fdiv(5).ceil - 1]
  end
end
```

```
laser_by_distance(43)  #=> :nitrogen 
laser_by_distance(95)  #=> :nitrogen 
laser_by_distance(126) #=> :xenon_ion 
laser_by_distance(154) #=> :coil 
laser_by_distance(170) #=> :co2 
laser_by_distance(200) #=> :helium_neon 
laser_by_distance(230) #=> :blaster
```

<sup>1. In the OP's hash, `:nuclear_pumped` and `:krypton` both had values of `170`. That's problematic. If, for example, the distance were `169` it's not clear which of the two lasers should be used. It make sense that every laser has a unique value. I've therefore changed `:nuclear_pumped` to `175`.</sup>

Comment: You're working really hard to justify the array here (e.g. non-guaranteed insertion order in a 12-year-old version of Ruby) when the `MIN_DISTANCE_BY_LASER` could be a hash in the format provided by the original question and the method you defined would still work the same because hashes are enumerable too.